# C# - Exclude lambda expression from code coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, code-coverage, coverlet

I have a particular third party class that has an event handler. I have setup `MyEventHandler` method which I am able to test using reflection, so I know that is well tested. However I am getting a missing line coverage where I setup the handler (since that part is never being called). How can I Exclude that from code coverage somehow? MyClass object is a sealed class so I can not mock it and invoke the handler via test.

```
MyClass myObj = new(); // sealed class, so can't mock using moq

myObj.OnEvent += () => 
    {
        MyEventHandler(); // This line is uncovered
    }
```

Things I have tried.

1. Making entire handler as a method, however again the actual lambda expression is still shown uncovered.
2. Marked the above method of setup with `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage`
3. I have also tried using `runsettings` file, which works however due to the `GeneratedCodeAttribute`/`CompilerGeneratedAttribute` exclusion, it also excludes my async functions, which is not desired.

How do I exclude the lambda expression from code coverage?

Comment: is the event-handler unconvered, or the assignment of that handler to the event?

Comment: So the assignment is your own code, yet you have no way of executing that statement in your test? How does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry maybe there's some confusion. The assignment line itself is covered. However since I can not invoke the event the lambda expression part is shown uncovered. I am also able to invoke the actual method so that is covered. I have split the handler on multiple lines to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so got this resolved. I am still posting here in case if it helps others in future. I have marked the event with `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` and that seems to exclude the event which in this case is what I wanted.

```
MyClass myObj = new();

myObj.OnEvent += [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] () => 
    {
        MyEventHandler();
    }
```